# Android setContentView from Handler?

Tags: android, handler, scrollview

I used the below code to populate screen.But it gives the runtime exception.How to solve this ?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

My code is:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

ArrayList ALobj;
Handler myHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
context = this;
ALobj=new ArrayList();  
ALobj.add(...);

myHandler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
  super.handleMessage(msg);   
  ALobj.add(....);
  populate_screen(ALobj);
 }
}

    populate_screen(ArrayList ALobj);

}

private void populate_screen(ArrayList obj){

ScrollView scrl=new ScrollView(context);

    LinearLayout llay=new LinearLayout(context); 
........
..........
............

    scrl.addView(llay);
setContentView(scrl);
}

.....
..........
.............
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
case 1:
Message msg = new Message();
myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is in the layout you are using under `scrollview`. You can use only single layout in `scrollview` not the nested layout......

refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that.I add only one Linearlayout in the ScrollView.

Comment: sorry I did a mistake.with in a loop I add the linearlayout to the Scroll view again . So I got the error.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think you put the multiple view into the scrollview that's why you getting this. try to put only one view

Comment: Thanks for the response .I put only one LinearLayout in the scrollview.